# Random crashes in Xamarin iOS app

Tags: iphone, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I am developing an iOS app using , everything going fine except than I am facing random crashes in my app. I have tried for iPhone 5,4s, iOS simulator (iOS 7 and iOS 8) . I am unable to find any cause for the crashes as crashes are just random at any place and anytime in the app. Also I am facing a weird issue where I am unable to raise event inn button touch in simulator while it is working fine in physical device. can anybody suggest me some tool or tip to cop with these crashes. I have tried to use Xamarin insight but no log is there.

Thanks

Comment: If those crashes are happening randomly in any place it may be device running out of memory, try to use method `override didReceiveMemoryWarning()` of ViewController to log if that method is being called. Btw are you able to debugg application on device or just run ? About simulator click event issue i wouldn't be worried those failed very often with many things

Comment: I would suggest you get the crash logs from the device as it would help understanding your problem.
A side from checking out of memory exceptions, as a guess, I would also check if it's a case of Null pointer exceptions - this is usually happens in monotouch when you decalre variables inside the methods instead of global class variables and then try to access them after GC.

Comment: Did you upload your dSYM to Insights? It won't show iOS without it.

Answer (score 1):

"Random" crashes almost always point to memory management problems (stack or heap corruption, over-releasing, etc).  Your best bet is to use guard malloc and zombies to track down these issues.  Instruments (a tool provided with Xcode) is a great asset for tracking down issues like yours.